# Kubernetes managed auto scaling group how to enable metrics collection

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, amazon-eks

We are using EKS in AWS to create and manage the autoscaling groups that the K8s cluster is using.
We want to be able to collect metrics from this auto scaling group but because we have not created the autoscaling group directly we cannot influence how it gets created and the "enable autoscaling group metrics collection" is not enabled.
We are interested in these metrics:

- GroupInServiceInstances
- GroupMaxSize

We are then setting an alert if the node pool gets exhausted where A == B.
Is there any way we can enable this in terraform other than manually?
If this cannot be done, are there any K8s metrics that we can expose that we can alert on if the underlying k8s managed asg is maxed out?

Answer (score 0):

To date, AWS doesn't support auto-scaling metric collection for managed node groups, though there is a [request](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/762) for it.

*Ironically*, it supports the same for self-managed node groups (a.k.a. unmanaged node groups). A corresponding pull request (PR) with an example on it—[here](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/pull/2055).